# Dividir fichero csv en n ficheros, pérdida de líneas cuando la divisón no es exacta

Tags: python, csv, div

Estoy desarrollando un script para dividir un fichero csv en tantos como se soliciten. Pero tengo un problema cuando la división de las lineas del fichero csv no es exacta con el número de ficheros que se quieren generar. ¿Cómo puedo recoger esas líneas sobrantes e incluirlas en el último fichero csv que genero?

He llegado a esto pero no hay manera...

```
def pass_file_to_list(filename, filediv):
    data_list = list()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in spamreader:
            bf_name = row
            data_list.append(bf_name)
    return divide_list(data_list, filediv)


def divide_list(data_list, filediv):
    lines_to_file = int(len(data_list) / filediv)
    lines_rest = int(len(data_list) % filediv)

    small_file_divided = list()

    for i in range(filediv):
        names = []
        for num in range(i * lines_to_file, (i + 1) * lines_to_file):
            names.append(data_list[num])

        small_file_divided.append(names)

    return small_file_divided


def write_csv_files(data_list, count):
    with open(name=path + '/subfile_' + str(count) + '.csv', mode='wb') as 
    csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', 
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for data in data_list:
            spamwriter.writerow(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

    parser = OptionParser(usage="%prog --filename --pos ")
    parser.add_option("-f", "--filename", action="store", type="string", 
    dest="filename", help="[REQUIRED] File name with the data to be searched")
    parser.add_option("-d", "--div", action="store", type="string", dest="div", 
    help="[REQUIRED] Number of files you want")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if not options.filename:
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        filename = options.filename
        path = "/".join(filename.split('/')[:-1])
    if not options.div:
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        filediv = int(options.div)

    file_list = pass_file_to_list(filename, filediv)

    count = 0
    for x in file_list:
        count += 1
        write_csv_files(x, count)
```

Comment: Hola SCarrasco. ¿Puedes explicar mejor por qué *"no hay manera"*? Muestranos los errores o el resultado actual vs el esperado. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Me refiero a que no he conseguido incluir esas lineas excedentes, no es que me de error de ejecución, si no que pierdo datos del fichero original.

Comment: Explicalo en la pregunta con ejemplos. Mira tambien [mcve]. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en ningún momento agregas las líneas que restan a la última lista de tu lista `small_file_divided` retornada por la función `divide_list`.

Bastaría con algo como esto:

```
    def divide_list(data_list, filediv):
        lines_to_file,  lines_rest = divmod(len(data_list), filediv)

        small_file_divided = list()

        for i in range(filediv):
            names = []
            for num in range(i * lines_to_file, (i + 1) * lines_to_file):
                names.append(data_list[num])
            small_file_divided.append(names)
        if lines_rest:
            small_file_divided[-1].extend(data_list[-lines_rest:]) # <<<<<<<<<<<

        return small_file_divided
```

Deberías considerar también comprobar que el número de ficheros no es mayor al número de filas del csv original.

---

Si se fuera a trabajar con csv muy extensos o pretendemos preservar RAM se puede simplificar el código haciendo uso de **iteradores**. Incluso para archivos pequeños esta opción es considerablemente más rápida y  eficiente. Se pueden crear los archivos sin tener que cargar el csv completo en memoria:

**Python 2.x:**

```
import csv
import itertools
import os

def rows_count(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        return sum(1 for row in f)

def get_chucks(it, lines, chucks):
    chuck_size = lines // chucks
    for i in xrange(1, chucks):
        yield i, itertools.islice(it, chuck_size)
    yield i + 1, it

def split_csv(file,  filediv,  header = True):
    with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        lines = rows_count(file)
        head = None
        if header:
            lines -= 1
            head = next(spamreader)
        if lines < filediv:
            raise ValueError("The number of rows ({}) is less than the number of output files ({})".format(lines, filediv))
        for i, data in get_chucks(spamreader, lines, filediv):
            path = "{}/subfile_{}.csv".format(os.path.dirname(file), i)
            write_csv_files(path, data, head)

def write_csv_files(path, data, header = None):
    with open(path, mode='wb') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        if header:
            spamwriter.writerow(header)
        spamwriter.writerows(data)
```

**Python 3:**

```
import csv
import itertools
import os

def rows_count(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return sum(1 for row in f)

def get_chucks(it, lines, chucks):
    chuck_size = lines // chucks
    for i in range(1, chucks):
        yield i, itertools.islice(it, chuck_size)
    yield i + 1, it

def split_csv(file,  filediv,  header = True):
    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        lines = rows_count(file)
        head = None
        if header:
            lines -= 1
            head = next(spamreader)
        if lines < filediv:
            raise ValueError("The number of rows ({}) is less than the number of output files ({})".format(lines, filediv))
        for i, data in get_chucks(spamreader, lines, filediv):
            path = "{}/subfile_{}.csv".format(os.path.dirname(file), i)
            write_csv_files(path, data, head)

def write_csv_files(path, data, header = None):
    with open(path, mode='w') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        if header:
            spamwriter.writerow(header)
        spamwriter.writerows(data)
```

Simplemente hay que llamar a la función `split_csv`. Dado como planteas tu problema, se presupone que el archivo original no tiene los nombres de las columnas en la primera línea (cabecera). En ese caso basta con pasar el argumento `header` como False:

```
split_csv(<Ruta csv>,  <Número de ficheros en los que dividirlo>. header = False)
```

En caso contrario tomará la primera fila como cabecera (nombre de las columnas) y será escrita también en todos los subficheros.

El código es en realidad simple y se basa en el uso de [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) para hacer simular un "slicing" del iterador retornado por `csv.reader`, de forma que `get_chucks` retorna un iterador con las filas necesarias por cada archivo de salida.

Answer (score 0):

Has pensado en la "Lógica" antes de picar código...

- Fichero CSV con **n** lineas
- Nos piden dividirlo en **m** ficheros

***Posibles casos:***

> m > n

Piden más ficheros que nº de lineas tiene el CSV

Posibles Soluciones:

a) Aviso de que no se permite. Abortar programa

b) Aviso de la situación. Solo se generan n ficheros (bucle que recorre el CSV, por cada linea de CSV se crea su fichero)

> m = n

bucle que recorre el CSV, por cada linea de CSV se crea su fichero

> m < n

El caso mas habitual.

Dividimos n entre m.

Nos apuntamos el Resultado (resultado) y el resto o módulo (resto).

```
Ejemplo:
101 lineas de CSV (n)
Nos piden 10 ficheros (m)
resultado (n/m) = 10
resto = 1
```

Bucle (con contador interno) recorriendo el CSV, se graba el contenido de la linea del CSV en el fichero, hasta que ese contador valga "resultado", se pone contador interno a cero y se graba en nuevo fichero... Así hasta que alcancemos el ultimo fichero a generar

Tras el ultimo bucle, tan solo hay que procesar las lineas que queden hasta el final del fichero CSV en el último fichero...

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera en `Python 3`:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
import math

# Generamos una función para leer las líneas de 
# un fichero.
def get_lines(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rt') as file:
        lines = 0
        for l in file: lines += 1
    return lines

# Función para dividir el fichero csv en varios
def split_csv(path_csv, splitby):

    with open(path_csv, 'r') as csvfile, ExitStack() as stack:
        # Líneas totales del fichero
        lines = get_lines(path_csv)

        # número de líneas por fichero (excepto el último)
        chunk_num_lines = math.floor(lines/splitby)
        chunk_num_lines = chunk_num_lines if chunk_num_lines > 0 else 1

        # Máximo de ficheros que podemos generar
        # por si ponemos un número "loco"
        max_files = min(lines, splitby)

        # Archivos que vamos a crear
        filenames = ['chunk{}.csv'.format(i) for i in range(0, max_files)]

        # Ficheros (Chunks)
        files = [ stack.enter_context(open(fname, 'wt')) for fname in filenames ]

        # Índice del fihcero actual
        file_index = 0
        # Máximo índice
        max_index = len(filenames) - 1

        # Recorremos el fichero
        for idx, line in enumerate(csvfile):
            # Obtenemos el chunk sobre el que escribir
            # en base al índice actual
            file = files[file_index]
            # Escribimos línea
            file.write(line)

            # Actualizamos el índice cuando hayamos escrito
            # el máximo de líneas para el fichero
            # escepto si file_index == max_index
            if (idx + 1) % chunk_num_lines == 0 and file_index < max_index:
                file_index += 1
```